# Can I make this java pluck() method more safe?

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I wrote this utility function:

```
public static <T> List<T> pluck(String fieldName, List list) 
        throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
    if (list.isEmpty()) {
        return new ArrayList<T>();
    }
    Class c = list.get(0).getClass();
    Field f = c.getField(fieldName);
    ArrayList<T> result = Lists.newArrayList();
    for (Object object : list) {
        result.add((T) f.get(object));
    }
    return result;
}
```

I copied the idea from [underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#pluck). The use case is:

```
ArrayList<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>;
people.add(new Person("Alice", "Applebee"));
people.add(new Person("Bob", "Bedmington"));
people.add(new Person("Charlie", "Chang"));

List<String> firstNames = pluck("firstName", people);
```

My problem is that if the caller gets the type wrong, no exception is thrown until the caller tried to get an object from the list. Ideally, I'd like to throw a `ClassCastException` from the `pluck` method itself. However, I don't see a way to access the type of the list on run time.

Is there some trick I can use to make sure the caller doesn't end up with an invalid list?

---

**Edit:** So using the feedback I got, a safe implementation would be:

```
public static <T,F> List<F> pluck(String fieldName, Class<F> fieldType, 
        List<T> list, Class<T> listType) 
        throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
    Field f = listType.getField(fieldName);
    ArrayList<F> result = new ArrayList<F>();
    for (T element : list) {
        result.add(fieldType.cast(f.get(element)));
    }
    return result;
}
```

But actually lambdaj seems to do what I wanted, so I guess I'll use that. Thanks mike!

**Disclaimer:** *LambdaJ* ( [@GoogleCode](https://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/) | [@GitHub](https://github.com/mariofusco/lambdaj) ) - This project is not maintained anymore since the release of JDK8 ([JSR 335](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=335), [JEP 126](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/126)).

Comment: [Lambdaj](https://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/) does this and much more, in a type safe fashion. It's one of my favorite libraries.

Comment: `list.get(0).getClass()` might not get you the right class. If `list.get(0)` is null it will crash. also, the later elements of `list` might not be instances of `list.get(0)`'s class

Comment: And to also pluck private class fields you may want to do this:                       Field f = listType.getDeclaredField(fieldName);
f.setAccessible(true); instead of doing Field f = listType.getField(fieldName);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your signature to as follows:

```
public static <T, F> List<F> pluck(String fieldName, Class<F> fieldType, 
                                           List<T> list, Class<T> listType)
```

The you have the list type and field type.

Answer (score 2):

Why dont you define the signature like this:

```
public static <T, U> List<T> pluck(String fieldName, Class<T> fieldType, List<U> list);
```

This would:

1) Force the client to supply the type of the field he wants to "pluck", so you can do proper type-checking in your method.

2) Force the client to supply a generic list from which to "pluck", so you prevent another error-source (the client supplying a list that contains objects of different types).

I think this is as safe as it can get..

Comment: "so you prevent another error-source (the client supplying a list that contains objects of different types)" It would not actually prevent anything; the way you have it written, it would accept any list.

Comment: @newacct It would accept just Lists that contain objects of a specific type. So you could not pass a list which contains different types of objects. The original signature would accept non-generic lists, which would increase the probability of objects being passed in that do not contain the field.

Comment: @newacct You could simply not pass the type 'List'. But you would have to pass a List<Person> for example - or List<Whatever>.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by invalid list? If you mean that they try to cast it to something it is not  then try changing the declaration to `public static <T> List<T> pluck(String fieldName, List<T> list)`.

I'm confused by the `However, I don't see a way to access the type of the list on run time.` comment. However, if I understand you correctly then: there is no "type" at runtime because generics in Java are implemented by "erasure". This means that the compiler checks at compile time that it works, and then turns it into regular casts like we had before generics. This was necessary they felt to enable backward and forward compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

You should use generics for the type parameter, and pass in the class object of the return type:

```
public static <TItem, TResult> List<TResult> pluck(String fieldName, List<TItem> list, Class<TResult> resultType) 
        throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
    if(list.isEmpty()) return new ArrayList<TResult>();

    Class c = list.get(0).getClass();
    Field f = c.getField(fieldName);
    ArrayList<TResult> result = new ArrayList<TResult>();
    for(Object object : list) {
        result.add(resultType.cast(f.get(object)));
    }
    return result;
}
```

Generally, when you get a warning about an unsafe cast to a type parameter, you should see if you can replace it with a call to `Class.cast`

Answer (score 1):

you can try the one given by Google collections library instead of maintaining a new one: Collections2.transform like this

```
Collection<Y> yourCollection...
...
Collection<X> expected = Collections2.transform(yourCollection, new Function<Y, X>() {
  public X apply(Y element) {
    return element.getX();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With Google's Guava collections library, you can use [`Collections2.transform()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Collections2.html#transform(java.util.Collection,%20com.google.common.base.Function)).

### Usage

Given an interface/class, e.g. called `Entity`, your class can implement/extend this.

```
public abstract class Entity {
    private long id;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

```java
public interface Entity {
    long getId();
}
```

Now you can Retrieve a list of each `Entity`'s IDs.

```
import com.google.common.base.Function;
import com.google.common.collect.Collections2;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Entity> entities = ...
        List<Long> ids = pluckIds(entities);
    }

    public static <E extends Entity> List<Long> pluckIds(List<E> list) {
        return new ArrayList<Long>(Collections2.transform(list, new Function<E, Long>() {
            public Long apply(E entity) {
                return entity.getId();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This is the safest you can get. This satisfies proper OOP principles and Java 5-7.

In Java 8, you can achieve the same effect with a stream, map, and lambda

```
public static <E extends Entity> List<Long> pluckIds(List<E> list) {
    return list.stream().map(e -> e.getId()).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

or

```
public static <T,F> List<F> pluck(String fieldName, Class<F> fieldType, 
        List<T> list, Class<T> listType) throws NoSuchFieldException,
        IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException {
    Field f = listType.getDeclaredField(fieldName);
    f.setAccessible(true);
    return list.stream().map(e -> {
        try { return fieldType.cast(f.get(e)); } catch (Exception e1) { return null; }
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are asking, but you could try:

```
Class c = list.get(0).getClass();
if (!c.equals(Person.class))
  throw new ClassCastException();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can cast the list to a `java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType` and checking that the array returned by `getActualTypeArguments()` contains the class you need. Other than that, you're out of luck.

Comment: This would only work if the list he got was, say, a subclass defined as `StringList extends ArrayList<String>`. For a list you get with `new ArrayList<String>()`, the type information isn't retained.